# C# can't add MediaPlayer object, get the following error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, media-player, windows-forms-designer, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am working on a project which needs to play a video on the screen. I created a form, dragged and dropped COM Component called Windows Media Player, customized buttons, OpenFileDialog, size etc. The object's name was let's say "axWindowsMediaPlayer1". I can control things, with methods like "axWindowsMediaPlayer1.play", "~.stop", "~.fullscreen = true" etc.

But today I just opened my project, and in form screen there was no drag&drop MediaPlayer element. But anyways, while running the program, the video was being shown, but there were no object named "axWindowsMediaPlayer1", on the form screen.

Then I tried to drag&drop another Media Player element, just to make sure there exists an "object". But I got the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2RYq.png).

I deleted everything in the Vide form now (both the design and code of the form), created a new form to do the same thing, in order to try some new methods, but now I can't even add this component to my form.

Can someone help me?

Comment: is your OS 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: it's 64 bit, and I chose 64bit as a building platform target

Comment: okay...reset your toolbox and try adding that again from the COM components list in your toolbox..see if it works.

Comment: no it still doesn't work

Comment: does that MediaPlayer element get added to the toolbox after adding it from the COM components?

Comment: yes it is, sorry for late replies

Comment: try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760916/failed-to-create-component-axhost-system-runtime-interopservices-comexception)... see if it works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, but when I tried to start a new project, it managed to add the mediaplayer tool

Comment: so were you able to access it?

Comment: yes, it works on a new project, but when I tried it in my main project, it's still the same, not working

Comment: any framework change in your new project?...like what framework version are you using _(in both the projects)_ ?

Comment: they both have .net framework 4.5

Comment: hmmm...quite weird. if you have the backup of the project, then add them to your new project by adding as _**Existing Items...**_ one by one because I am not sure what might have gone wrong...is it the designer.cs file or something...not sure.

Comment: this might work, but I'm not too sure if my project will do the same things as before, because I have added some dll's which can't be added manually, and this makes me unsure if I want to start a new project. That might be matter of 64/32 bit. Mine was 64, maybe It works on 32

Comment: it's worth giving a try...since you can't proceed until the problem is resolved.